# mysql error Access denied for user with go-sql-driver when used in separate package

Tags: mysql, go

I am getting the following error when using with go-sql-driver with mysql and gorp when using in a separate package called dbutil
 Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
package dbutil

import (
    "cropz/structs"
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/coopernurse/gorp"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "log"
)

func InitDB() *gorp.DbMap {
    // connect to db
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:pass@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/jsl")
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    checkErr(err, "Ping failed")

    // construct a gorp DbMap
    dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.MySQLDialect{"InnoDB", "UTF8"}}

    return dbmap
}


package main

func main() {

    dbmap := dbutil.InitDB()
    err := dbmap.Db.Ping()
    checkErr(err, "Ping failed")
}
```

If I have the initDB() function in the main package, it works fine.

This happens only if used with martini framework and dbutil in separate package. With martini framework and in the same package it still works.

I am using windows, MySQL-5.0.22. Please help.

thanks,
Krishna

Comment: i guess, err is in `sql.Open`. try `con, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")`

Comment: It works if the intiDB() code is in the same package. It gives error only if it is in different package.

Comment: I have tested with just the driver and database/sql commands, which works fine even in different package. I guess, the problem is when using with gorp. Still trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the .a files generated in the pkg folder and then didn't get the access denied error.

Comment: I delete that, but still sunk.

Answer (score 0):

Your error looks like a login failure. Is your DSN setup appropriately?

Other than that you should remove the `defer db.Close()`

I believe you should only be closing the Db when you are actually done with it according to the spec.

When I run your code I actually get this error

```
panic: sql: database is closed
```

Comment: The same initDB() code works if it is in the main package. It gives error only if it's in different package.

Comment: So very basic question. Did you go install the other package?

Comment: I didn't install explicitly. I just add the dir path to the gopath. As I said in the comment to the question, with just sql driver in different package it still works. when I use gorp it gives the error.